# Invoke grep from a shell script and keep the colored patterns

Tags: shell, colors, terminal

For some mysterious reason, whenever I run grep from a "standalone" shell script as opposed to a simple function, the coloring of the output is not preserved.

*Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?*

This is best illustrated with an example:
[image]

Comment: this is not what I wrote !, @Ярослав Рахматуллин edited my post completelly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try in your script :

```
grep --color
```

But please, no need to

```
echo `ls` |  grep ".txt"
```

just

```
ls -1 | grep --color ".txt"
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' | grep --color ".txt"
```

See http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

**EDIT**

To change the defautl colors of grep, see `man grep` and search `GREP_COLORS`

Comment: tnx, it works it need 10 min to pass before I accept this..., I more question is it possible to control the color ? I mean it is always red, is it possible to be set for example to green

Comment: How can we copy that to a file (with the color and other formatting) will re-direct work?